# Trouble with basic modulus understanding

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, for-loop, modulus

I'm a newbie in JavaScript programming. When studying I encountered following code:

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (i % 2) j += i;
}
```

Running the code returns **9**. I completely understand how `for` loops work and how modulus operates (for example `23 % 7` returns `2`).

However, I'm having troubles understanding this particular code - especially the `if` statement argument. Would somebody be kind enough to explain this to me?

Comment: First this return `j=0; i=1`. Second `if(i%2)` is similar to `if(i % 2 !== 0)`. Basically if expects boolean value and `i % 2` will return a numeric value. And `0` is a falsey value. So if `i%2` returns `0`, if will be skipped.

Comment: The statement `if (i % 2)` is equivalent to `if (i % 2 !== 0)`.

Comment: I made a mistake copying the code! It's updated now to `for (i = 0, j = 0; i <= 6; i++)`

Comment: `j += 0` doesn't do anything, are you sure about that too?

Comment: Mistake after mistake copying the code... I should have been more careful. So sorry. It's `j += i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you add the odds.

```
if (i % 2)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (i % 2 !== 0)
```

```js
var i, count = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (i % 2) {
        console.log(i, i % 2),
        count += i;
    }
}

console.log(count);
```

```js
var i, count = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        console.log(i, i % 2),
        count += i;
    }
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It makes everything crystal clear right now!

Answer (score 0):

The reason `j = 9` in the end is because for ever uneven number `i` is added to `j`

`x%2` where `x` is an even number will result in `0` which in turn evaluates to `false` within the `if`.

`x%2` where `x` is an uneven number will result in `1` which in turn evaluates to `true` within the `if`.

Therefore every time `x%y` evaluates to `true` the current value of `i` is added to `j`

Loop starts

1: `i=0` ► `0%2=0` ► `j=0`
2: `i=1` ► `1%2=1` ► `j=1 //(0+1)`
3: `i=2` ► `2%2=0` ► `j=1`
4: `i=3` ► `3%2=1` ► `j=4 //(1+3)`
5: `i=4` ► `4%2=0` ► `j=4`
6: `i=5` ► `5%2=1` ► `j=9 //(4+5)`

Loop ends

```js
for (i = 0, j = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  if (i % 2) j += i; // for every uneven number i is added to j
}
console.log(j)
```